# Emulating fragment navigation inside a shadowroot document (onclick -> scrollIntoView?)

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I have a large technical document, in HTML, that contains text, css, and embedded images.  We are moving it (the entire document) to inside a shadowroot, for CSS isolation from the viewer webapp.

Before we moved it into a shadowroot, the document html structure was this, and it worked great for navigation inside the same page:

```
See <a href="#graphic-001">Figure 1</a>
... lots of text ...
<div id="graphic-001"><img src=base64data...></div>
```

Now that it is inside a shadowroot, this no longer works, sadly.

I tried this:

```
 See <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('GRAPHIC-01').scrollIntoView()">Figure 1</a>
```

But it does not work (element is null), and neither does onclick="...".  What is the magic sauce here?

Note that I have no idea what the global shadowroot element is, it does not have a defined id.  Also, I can only write html/javascript code that lives inside the shadowroot.

Edit: I just want the user to be able to click on a link and scroll to somewhere else in the document (same page).  I don't care if it shows in browser url or uses history.